# Android System WebView - jun-2023 update - causing 40 second delay in webRTC ICE candidate selection

Tags: android, webview, webrtc, ice

We have an Android application that uses webview to handle our webRTC connections. Since the jun-2023 update (to version 114.x) we have been experiencing the dreaded 40 second delay when webRTC goes into ICE candidate selection.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: are you not using trickle-ice and waiting for onicecandidate with event.candidate == null  (or gatheringstate to complete) to fire?
That can *cause* such a delay but there should not have been any changes in M114.

Comment: We are using the JSSIP library, and from their code it does look like they are waiting for gatheringstate to complete.

// Resolve right away if 'pc.iceGatheringState' is 'complete'.

/**
 * Resolve right away if:
 * - 'connection.iceGatheringState' is 'complete' and no 'iceRestart' constraint is set.
 * - 'connection.iceGatheringState' is 'gathering' and 'iceReady' is true.
 */

I guess I should ask them.

Comment: @PhilippHancke -  Update: We have discovered that by switching away from the Google STUN servers (e.g. to Twilio STUN server instead) then we no longer get the 40 second delay. We continue to investigate.

Comment: That points in the right direction, answered below. I'll poke the jssipguys.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7844

The Google STUN server you used has AAAA records for IPv6 and this times out on the machines you are looking at, probably because there is no IPv6 uplink.

Twilio's STUN server only has IPv4 A records (or rather a CNAME pointing to an A record) so no attempt is made to gather a server-reflexive IPv6 candidate.

This timeout is intentional. If you are ok with not supporting server-reflexive IPv6 candidates you should send the offer after gathering a srflx IPv4 candidate instead of waiting for the gathering state change to completed. Or rather jssip should, I'd suggest filing a bug.

Now why that behavior changed in the June 2023 update of Android WebView... possibly something DNS related.